# Retag all [service] questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, burninate-request

Currently there is a [service](/questions/tagged/service) tag.

It has **9,333 questions**

It usually contains questions about

- [android-service](/questions/tagged/android-service) ([3,881](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service+android) with [service](/questions/tagged/service) and [android](/questions/tagged/android))
- [windows-service](/questions/tagged/windows-service) ([870](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service+windows) with [service](/questions/tagged/service) and [windows](/questions/tagged/windows))
- [web-services](/questions/tagged/web-services) ([388](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service+web) with [service](/questions/tagged/service) and [web](/questions/tagged/web))

I believe we should retag that questions with the more specific one, but with that large number of questions I believe it is not really doable by hand.

[There are 3,705 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service+-android+-windows+-web+-soap+-rest+-web-services+-windows-services+-winapi) tagged [service](/questions/tagged/service) not [android](/questions/tagged/android) not [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) not [web](/questions/tagged/web) not [soap](/questions/tagged/soap) not [rest](/questions/tagged/rest) not [web-services](/questions/tagged/web-services) not [windows-services](/questions/tagged/windows-services) not [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi)

I believe that the other questions could be retagged en-masse:

- [android](/questions/tagged/android) -> [android-service](/questions/tagged/android-service)
- [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) or [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi) -> [windows-services](/questions/tagged/windows-services)
- [web](/questions/tagged/web), [soap](/questions/tagged/soap) or [rest](/questions/tagged/rest) -> [web-services](/questions/tagged/web-services)

There is also the highly related tag [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), which looks like it could map to [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf), although some of the questions are about [windows-services](/questions/tagged/windows-services)

Comment: .net-service isn't a thing. You use C# to write a windows service, a web service or a windows phone 8 service, etc. Heck, I wouldn't be surprised if there was a compiler out there which allowed you to write an android service in C#.

Comment: Sorry, there was a small misspelling there (it should be [tag:.net-services]) Anyway, I believe [tag:wcf] is better.

Comment: .net-services is an unhelpfully broad tag (you may as well say .net-program), probably chosen by hobbyists or new programmers. Only 11 questions have been tagged with it (and none of the authors had very high rep) and a description was written less than a month ago. There is no wiki. In addition, C# can be compiled into non-.NET binaries (thinking Mono, but there are other compilers as well). Overall, I think the plan to retag C# questions is misguided - I would recommend against it.

Comment: @JDB I just mention it. I don't think [tag:service] is a good tag, so burniate it. But the question is how should [tag:c#] questions be retaged? Is it possible to find a good unambigous tag that could replace that? I don't think so, but I documented at least this wasted effort.