# Why edits gets rejected as 'too minor' when retagging google-tagged questions?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Why edits gets rejected as "edit is too minor" when retagging [google](/questions/tagged/google)-tagged questions and sometimes it is approved?

If we want to clean up questions with [google](/questions/tagged/google)-tag, I think those edits should get approved, even if there is no other edits made to that question.

Comment: most of your suggestions were got approved. As you suggested more edits with same reason, reviewers got confused that you are reviewing for reps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably saw this recent question: [Cleaning Up Google Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210920/cleaning-up-google-tags)

As you can see, there are mixed views on whether or not tag-only edits are too minor. A majority of your edits were approved though.

For the most part, these edits (in excess) clog up the Suggested Edits queue. If you are going to make strictly tag only edits, it is encouraged that you have at least 2k reputation so that the edits don't have to be approved.

There was actually a feature request 2 days ago: [Lower the reputation requirement for tag-only edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210709/lower-the-reputation-requirement-for-tag-only-edits)

In the meantime, I would suggest editting other things in the question at the same time.

For instance, in [this edit that was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3555315), you could have removed:

> Thanks and sorry for my bad english

You could have also improved the grammar. In doing so, I wouldn't consider this edit to have been 'too minor', and I definitely would have approved it.

Comment: Even if you do have more than 2k reputation, you still should really be fixing all issues as an edit moves the question to the front page.

Comment: @Dukeling Yea, that's a valid point. I neglect doing so when I am retagging hundreds of questions though. I will removed thanks statements and noise, but I definitely don't stop to fix grammar.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that thread, and thought that I can help in this project. And I also look if I can somehow improve questions another way, like this http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18691102/revisions, but I'm not fully familiar yet what things I should remove/add to questions. Like that you suggested, I didn't know it is ok to remove that line. But I want to learn, so thanks for good answer.

Comment: You can also say that this is a part of the Google tags cleanup. Explain more in the edit reason.

Comment: @juniperi About the "thanks" line - see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Answer (score 2):

For this specific cleanup of the [google](/questions/tagged/google) removal (thanks, by the way! Every little bit helps!), you may want to create an edit explanation that you use each time that gives the reviewer the ability to figure out what you're doing if interested, for instance:

> Fixed tags (removed [google] as discussed in meta: meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/210920/cleaning-up-google-tags)

In addition, [as I said in that post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211031/209637) in regards to action items:

> Naturally, if there are quality or other issues that can be fixed at the same time, please do that too

Here are some things to look out for:

1. If the question is very low quality, flag as 'very low quality'
2. Remove any 'thanks' or 'please help'
3. Fix any obvious spelling or grammar errors
4. Add any code blocks if necessary
5. Fix the title if it is unclear or doesn't explain what is in the question

As explained by JoshC, the minor edit system is in place because every time you suggest an edit, someone else has to review it. If you didn't make a good edit comment, or you didn't fix other obvious mistakes, people are more likely to reject it undoing the work you put in. While it is more work while you are under 2k rep, the extra effort is worth it.

I don't want to discourage anyone from improving the site through suggested edits, just be aware that you are held to a higher standard when you do it. Thanks again for the help!